# How to replace ZFS pool root with a snapshot after replication

Tags: zfs, replication, snapshot

I'm replacing some failing disks with new ones, and rather than replace them one by one I have created a new ZFS pool on the new disks, and copied the old pool over to the new one.  I did this at the pool level so all the volumes within would be copied.

```
# zfs snapshot -r oldpool@moving
# zfs send -R oldpool@moving | zfs recv -F -v newpool
```

This worked, and I now have the `@moving` snapshot on the new pool:

```
# zfs list -t snapshots
oldpool@moving
oldpool/vol1@moving
oldpool/vol2@moving
newpool@moving
newpool/vol1@moving
newpool/vol2@moving
```

Now I can already see all the files in the `newpool` mount point, and even modify them, even though they are from a snapshot (everything I read said snapshots are read-only and must be cloned to become writable, so I'm not sure whether `zfs recv` already created clones of the snapshot or what).

So I am wondering how to discard the `newpool@moving` snapshot and promote this state to be the new pool (i.e. the base state with no snapshots at all).

I tried cloning the snapshot however this just appeared to move the snapshot to a different path:

```
# zfs clone newpool@moving newpool/clone
# zfs promote newpool/clone
# zfs destroy newpool@moving
could not find any snapshots to destroy; check snapshot names.
# zfs list -t snapshots
oldpool@moving
oldpool/vol1@moving
oldpool/vol2@moving
newpool/clone@moving    # was newpool@moving
newpool/vol1@moving
newpool/vol2@moving
```

It seems to have renamed the top-level volume and snapshot (but not any of the child volumes within it), and kept it as a snapshot instead of turning it into a "base volume with no snapshot".

Before I make anything worse, what am I missing?  How can I make the snapshot on `newpool` go away by merging everything into the base volumes, so that it reflects the state of `oldpool` as it was before I took the snapshot in order to replicate it onto `newpool`?

Answer (score 2):

I think I worked this one out.  The original situation (before I messed up with `zfs clone`) was that the filesystem was copied and a matching snapshot was created to assist with future incremental updates (with `zfs send -i`).  It was as if the files had been copied and then a snapshot created, meaning any subsequent changes went to the underlying filesystem, and I could roll those changes back to the snapshot if I wished (just like the source pool I'd created the original snapshot in).

Since I didn't need this, all I had to do was just delete the snapshots:

```
# zfs destroy -v -r newpool@moving
# zfs destroy -v -r oldpool@moving
```

And the two pools were now identical.

However in this case, first I had to fix the mess I'd created with `zfs promote`.  This had promoted the dataset root to be a clone, effectively changing this structure:

```
newpool
 |
 +-- vol1
 |
 +-- vol2
```

Into this structure:

```
newpool
 |
 +-- clone
      |
      +-- vol1
      |
      +-- vol2
```

The solution was to undo this promotion of the clone, which I managed to do like this:

```
# zfs snap -r newpool@s1   # Not sure if this is actually needed or not
# zfs promote newpool
```

Once that was done everything was close to back the way it was just after the `zfs recv` parameter, I just had to delete the clone as normal (`zfs destroy newpool/clone`) and the extra `@s1` snapshot.